# Russian letters are not displayed on nodes in Reagraph

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, graph

I am making a React application with drawing data on a graph, I ran into a problem that Russian characters are not displayed on the nodes.
I tried to connect fonts by link in labelFontUrl, but an error occurs. Using reagraph for graphs [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odxcx.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh9w6.png)

im tryin to use troika-three-text but have the same text in error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a VITE so to import a svg/png or like in my case .ttf u need to write
in vite-env.d.ts:

declare module '*.png'
declare module '*.svg'
declare module '*.ttf'